# Matlab calling python, returning vector, str2num not working on returned vector

Tags: python, string, matlab, numbers

I am writing a piece of Matlab code in which it makes a number of calls to python. These calls are returning the data as a string. The problem I am having is converting the string to a number. Its not as simple as that though, for two of my calls it converts the strings no problem but for this third one it only works if the vector does not exceed one line in the Matlab command window.

My code is as follows:

**Call one**

*Matlab:*

```
wind_direction=sprintf('python C:\\Users\\pduffy\\Documents\\MMI_Raptur_V2\\Python\\Distributions\\CDF.py %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f', N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW,Iterations);                
                    [status,Wind_Dir_string] = system (wind_direction);
                    Wind_Dir_shape=str2num(Wind_Dir_string);
                    Wind_Dir= reshape(Wind_Dir_shape,[],1)
```

*Python*

```
import sys
import scipy.stats


def CDF_Random(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW,Iterations):


    WindDir = (0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315)
    Freq=(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW)

    cdf=scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(WindDir,Freq))

    cdf_rand=cdf.rvs(size=Iterations)    
    return (cdf_rand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = float(sys.argv[1])
    NE = float(sys.argv[2])
    E = float(sys.argv[3])
    SE = float(sys.argv[4])
    S = float(sys.argv[5])
    SW = float(sys.argv[6])
    W = float(sys.argv[7])
    NW = float(sys.argv[8])
    Iterations = float(sys.argv[9])
    sys.stdout.write(str(CDF_Random(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW,Iterations)))
```

**Call two**

*Matlab*

```
fragment_velocity_string=sprintf('python C:\\Users\\pduffy\\Documents\\MMI_Raptur_V2\\Python\\Distributions\\beta.py %f %f %f %f', lower, mode, upper, Iterations);                
                    [status,Vf_rpm_string] = system (fragment_velocity_string);
                    Vf_rpm_shape=str2num(Vf_rpm_string);
                    Vf_rpm= reshape(Vf_rpm_shape,[],1)
```

*Python*

```
import sys
import numpy.random

def Beta_Random(lower,mode,upper,Iterations):

    Iterations=int(Iterations)   
    mean=(1/6)*(lower+upper+(4*mode))
    a=((mean-lower)*((2*mode)-lower-upper))/((mode-mean)*(upper-lower))
    b=(a*(upper-mean))/(mean-lower)


    beta_rand=numpy.random.beta(a,b,[Iterations])

    rand_sample=(beta_rand*(upper-lower))+lower

    return (rand_sample)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lower = float(sys.argv[1])
    mode = float(sys.argv[2])
    upper = float(sys.argv[3])
    Iterations = float(sys.argv[4])
    sys.stdout.write(str(Beta_Random(lower,mode,upper,Iterations)))
```

**Call three** the one causing me problems

*Matlab*

```
 wind_speed_string=sprintf('python C:\\Users\\pduffy\\Documents\\MMI_Raptur_V2\\Python\\Distributions\\Weibull.py %f %f %f', alpha, beta, Iterations);
                   [status,Vw_resultant_string] = system (wind_speed_string) ;
                    Vw_shape=str2num(Vw_resultant_string);
                    Vw_resultant= reshape(Vw_shape,[],1)
```

*Python*

```
import sys
import numpy.random

def Weibull_Random(alpha,beta,Iterations):



    a=alpha
    b=beta


    weibull_rand=numpy.random.weibull(a,[Iterations])

    rand_sample=((weibull_rand)*b)

    return (rand_sample)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alpha = float(sys.argv[1])
    beta = float(sys.argv[2])
    Iterations = float(sys.argv[3])
    sys.stdout.write(str(Weibull_Random(alpha,beta,Iterations)))
```

So what ever number I set `Iterations` to, this number of values is returned to Matlab. In all three Matlab codes I use `str2num`to covert the data received from Python and then reshape it to create a single column matrix.

For the third piece of code, the one causing me problems, I have tried rounding the number in python to four decimal places using `numpy.around`. I chose four as this is the same as Matlab converts to using `str2num`. I aslo tried using `str2double` but got a single `NAN` value returned.

So as I said Matlab will convert all the received data from python to a number for any amount of `Iterations` for the first and secound piece of code. But will only work when the vector does not exceed one line for the third peice of code, so at the moment it only works for `Iterations = 6`

This seems very strange to me as all the sections of code are very similar except the functions they preform in Python.

I'm using windows 7, Matlab 2012, Python 3 with Numpy and Scipy (pyzo2013b)

As always thank you very much for your time and thank you for any help you may be able to offer.

**Edit 1- Problem Solved**

I solved the problem by using `Wind_Dir_vector=regexprep(Wind_Dir_string,'\n',' ')` which replaced the new line characters with space characters. I think the problem was with Matlab not been able to create an array when the results did not have the same amounts of columns in each line, becuase it did not know what to put in the remaining cells.

Hope that made sense, I'm in  a bit of a rush.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my question as an edit within my question but I thought I better put an actual answer down so people in the future may find a solution a bit easier.

The problem was that Matlab tried to put the imported data into a square matrix and if there were not a enough values imported to create a perfectly square matrix it did not know what to put in the last few columns. So when I tried to convert the strings of data to numbers `(str2num)` it was confused.

So what I did was remove all the newline characters from the imported data effectively making the data a nice long list and then used the`(str2num)` function and it worked perfectly.

The new line characters were removed using this piece of code.

```
Wind_Dir_vector=regexprep(Wind_Dir_string,'\n',' ')
```